# Facet count on grouping result

Tags: java, solr, facet

Trying to get row count from solr after grouping. PFB the sample SOLR document structure:

```
doc{
    String id,
    String date,
    String category,
    //Other properties
}
```

There are multiple rows present for an id w.r.t date. One **id** can have different **category** with different **date**
I need to find the count of id(s) present in each category with latest date present for that **id**. There are multiple different **id**(s) present with respect to **category**

I have tried grouping with facet, but unable to get desired result.

```
Sample Query: 
group=true&group.main=true&group.field=id&group.limit=1&facet=true&group.facet=true&facet.field=category
sort:date desc
rows:1
```

However the results coming are incorrect.

Example

```
id   date      category
1    20190831   A
1    20190731   A
1    20190630   A
1    20190531   B
1    20190430   B
```

Results i am getting are:

```
 "facet_fields": {
      "category": [
        "A",
        2,
        "B",
        2
      ]
```

Desired results are:

```
 "facet_fields": {
      "category": [
        "A",
        1
      ]
```

Since the latest date entry is with **A** category.

Comment: This seems to be a match for [Collapse and Expand](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collapse-and-expand-results.html) - I haven't used it myself, but as all downstream (i.e. faceting, etc.) work with the collapsed set, using `max` with date (it says numeric field, so you might need to adjust it depending on type).